# Algolia Events triggered from Segment but not shown in algolia dashboard

Tags: android, flutter, algolia, segment

**Algolia Events triggered from Segment but not shown in algolia dashboard**

I have used the **algolia_helper_flutter: ^0.3.1** as the zip and integrated directly to the project, because the plugin is not merged properly so we don't have the **click anayltics** param.After integrating it directly i can trigger the event of segment using algolia params also.

```
Segment.track(eventName: 'test', options: {
      'product_id': '507f1f77bcf86cd799439011',
      'sku': 'G-32',
      'category': 'Games',
      'name': 'Monopoly: 3rd Edition',
      'brand': 'Hasbro',
      'variant': '200 pieces',
      'price': 18.99,
      'quantity': 1,
      'coupon': 'MAYDEALS',
      'position': 3,
      'url': 'https://www.example.com/product/path',
      'image_url': 'https://www.example.com/product/path.jpg',

//algolia params
      'index': 'my-algolia-index',
      'eventType': 'click',
      'queryID': _shoeSearcher.responses,
      'objectID': '131280270'
    });
```

In segment the event delivered successfully, but i cannot see any trace in the algolia dashboard.[Segment event delivered screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAKOU.png).

[Algolia Dashboard event page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW3bR.png).

Am expecting to visible the event in algolia.